# How do I solve this using calculus

Tags: calculus

Given:

$$\sin x - \cos x = 1/3$$ solve for $\sin(2x).$

As the title states, how would I solve this? It's a question in my textbook but it seems like algebra to me. Would I differentiate both sides or do I have to use trig identities to work my way?

Answer (score 6):

This really isn't a calculus question, just a trigonometry question.

Square it, and you get $$\sin^2 x -2\sin x\cos x +\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{9}.$$ Now use $$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$$ and $$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$$

Comment: Why can you put in -sin2x in to the equation like that?

Answer (score 0):

For real numbers $A, B$ not both $0$ there exists $y$ with $\cos y=\frac {A}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}$ and $\sin y=\frac {B}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}},$ so $A\sin x+B\cos x=(\sqrt {A^2+B^2}\;)\sin (x+y).$

With $A=1$ and $B=-1$ we have $y\in \{ (-\pi /4)+2\pi n\}_{n \in \mathbb Z}   .$ And we have  $\sin x-\cos x =(\sqrt 2)\sin (x+y)=1/3.$ So $\sin (x+y)=1/(3\sqrt 2\;).$ I leave the rest to you.